# Too Many connections for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am working on MongoDB with grails. When I run "mongod" command its giving me number of connections around 135 and still its getting connections.

How can I get only one connection.

Any help good for me.

Comment: Your code can be the only thing causing this, and there is no code in your question. Look for basically multiple parts of your code that establish connections as there really only should be one part only. Also look for possible concurrent on unresolved operations and cursors. Those are the only reasons we can point to without code.

Comment: @navneet35371 Well if you read the question then the problem explained is "too many connections" as I have already changed the title to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Every driver for MongoDB maintains a connection pool in order to prevent the overhead for a three way handshake. What you see is expected behavior.

## A bit more detailed.

Let's assume you have a web page which displays all your notes. When your controller is called, you query all notes for the requesting user and display it using a GSP. Now, image you have two concurrent users. If you had only one connection, one of them had to wait until the results for the other user were returned. Not much latency when talking of two concurrent users, granted. But now imagine you had 100 or 1000 concurrent users... They'd wait forever, possibly even running into timeouts.

Ok, now we have agreed on why we need multiple connections, let's find out why they are that many. When a socket connection is opened, a few things happen. Basically, one could transcribe it like this

> C: Hi, Server!
>
> S: Hi, Client!
>
> C: Oh, you are talking with me! Cool!
>
> S: Yes, and I am a MongoDB server, version 3.0!
>
> C: Awesome, just what I wanted! Can you give me your status?
>
> S: Sure! I am a secondary of a replica set called "replSet", the primary is on 192.168.0.1 and another secondary can be found on 192.168.0.100
>
> C: Darn, need to talk to a primary! But let's keep in touch!
>
> S: Sure! Will be here if you need me!

Now, the client would open a connection to the primary, and pretty much the same happens, only when the server identifies itself as a primary, the two start to exchange documents. Even when we have a standalone server, this process takes a while. Not long, but it will add up adding latency for delivering answers for no good reasons. An established connection is cheap, both on the server and on the client side. For the server it is slightly over a megabyte, and on the client side it shouldn't be more than a few kilobyte of RAM. So with preallocated connections, you save time and thus provide better performance at the cost of a a small fraction of RAM.

**What happens if all connections are used?**

Usually, only a fraction of the maximum possible connections are established. If a certain number of connections are left, a couple of new connections are established. This goes on and on. If more than another number of connections are free, a few get torn down. In some cases, all possible connections are stablished. If more requests are made, the individual request has to wait until a connection is freed.

You can find out how many connections would be possible by issuing

```
db.serverStatus()
```

On the command line. The `connections` field shows you how many current and available connections you have.